# How to divide the values of a column in one df with another df's column values based on a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dfs of **variable length** and trying to create a new column **df1['CONV_AMOUNT']** by dividing **df1['AMOUNT']** by **df2['VALUE']** if **df1['CURR_CODE']** matches **df2['CURR_CODE']**.

But after merging im not getting the expected result.

**df1:**

[image]
**df2:**
[image]

What i have tried from SO solution [Multiplying columns in separate pandas dataframe based on similar column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54964836/multiplying-columns-in-separate-pandas-dataframe-based-on-similar-column-values) is :

```
df1['CONV_AMOUNT'] = df1.merge(df2).assign(soln=lambda df: df.AMOUNT / df.VALUE).soln
```

**What im getting as ouptut which is wrong(***df1***):**

[image]

**Expected df1:**

[image]

I couldn't able to figure what im missing or doing wrong here. Any help/suggestion is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: please copy and paste your dataframe as code/text instead of as image

Comment: Dataframes have huge data, thats why i tried to put some sample data