# Multiply multiple columns based on similar column IDs in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have two data frames DF1 and DF2. Both Df have the common columns ID. I want to perform the multiplication of each columns based on the common id column and make a new data frame to store it.

I have attached below the expected output.

my try

```
df1.soln = df1.merge(df2).assign(soln=lambda df: df.number * df.mult).soln
```

**DF1**

[image: Df1]

**Df2**

[image]

**Expected DF after multiplication based on common ID in ID column**

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54964836/multiplying-columns-in-separate-pandas-dataframe-based-on-similar-column-values

Comment: any other solution ??

Comment: kindly provide reproducible examples. Also, is there anything wrong with the solution referred to by Michael?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set 'ID' ax index first, then multiply:

```
(df1.set_index('ID')*df2.set_index('ID')).reset_index()
```

*NB. You should provide your data as text or, better, DataFrame constructors, this would make your question non-ambiguous*

Comment: Hi @Mozway
Code is working fine, but i want slight change in the equation, i did it but not getting expected output. Plz can you check below code for this equation. 

`abs((df1.set_index('ID')-df2.set_index('ID')/df1.set_index('ID')) * 100).reset_index()`
that code giving wrong output.

Comment: There are parentheses mismatches I think. Not sure what the expected output is as you didn't provide it, but try: `(abs((df1.set_index('ID')-df2.set_index('ID'))/df1.set_index('ID')) * 100).reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you don't need `merge`:

```
>>> df1
     20/12/2020  21/12/2020  20/12/2020  21/12/2020
A_B           1           2           3           4
B_C           5           6           7           8
A_C           9          10          11          12

>>> df2
     20/12/2020  21/12/2020  20/12/2020  21/12/2020
A_C           9          10          11          12
A_B           1           2           3           4
B_C           5           6           7           8

>>> df1 * df2
     20/12/2020  21/12/2020  20/12/2020  21/12/2020
A_B           1           4           9          16
A_C          81         100         121         144
B_C          25          36          49          64

# Just for readability
>>> df1.mul(df2).reindex(df1.index)
     20/12/2020  21/12/2020  20/12/2020  21/12/2020
A_B           1           4           9          16
B_C          25          36          49          64
A_C          81         100         121         144
```

Comment: I am getting error. Row numbers are not same in my data frame. 

Error msg : can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: You have to set `ID` as index first.